# Exception in plugin Android Support - The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

I got this error message, "Error on line 67: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.", when I tried to run my app.

Below is the detail

```
Error on line 67: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.: Error on line 67: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 67: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:364)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.readSettings(SettingsConnectionService.java:72)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getSettingValue(SettingsConnectionService.java:112)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getServiceUrl(SettingsConnectionService.java:104)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStatisticsService.areStatisticsAuthorized(AndroidStatisticsService.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.addBuildRecordImmediately(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent$1.run(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 2195; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    ... 18 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 2195; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:364)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.readSettings(SettingsConnectionService.java:72)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getSettingValue(SettingsConnectionService.java:112)
    at com.intellij.facet.frameworks.SettingsConnectionService.getServiceUrl(SettingsConnectionService.java:104)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStatisticsService.areStatisticsAuthorized(AndroidStatisticsService.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.addBuildRecordImmediately(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent$1.run(StudioBuildStatsPersistenceComponent.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

I tried to delete my Android studio and Android SDK tools and install again, but it didn't work.

Anybody know the answer!?

Comment: Well what's on line 67, column 2195 of the relevant file?

Comment: I don't know what is "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException", is that a original file in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved.

I try to rebuild the project and run the app again, and it works.

Thanks a lot!!